# Difference between /etc/security/pam_env.conf and /etc/environment + making sudo read pam_env.conf

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, pam, environment

I struggle to see the difference between `pam_env.conf` and `/etc/environment`. To me they both do the same thing, with a difference syntax. The manpages were no help. So what is the difference?

Additionally, I'd like to find a way to add paths to the `PATH` environment variable for all users. Adding them to the two aforementioned files works for all users, but doesn't work with sudo, as can be verified by running `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`.

To solve that problem, I believe I should edit the file `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, but what should I put in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 fundamental differences between `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` and `/etc/environment`.

1. **The order in which PAM processes them.**

   `/etc/environment` is parsed first, but anything defined here is overridden by definitions for those same variables if they also exist in `pam_env.conf`.
   However, it's possible to subsume + extend the variables from `/etc/environment` in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, e.g.:

   ```
   /etc/security/pam_env.conf

   PATH   DEFAULT=${PATH}:/usr/sbin
   ```
2. **Variable expansion**

   a.  `/etc/environment` is not a script, but a set of assignment expressions, i.e. `${PATH}` is not expanded, but used literally.

   b.  `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` is a different animal altogether.  It's not a script per se; it's still just a set of KEY=VALUE assignments, but PAM can expand existing variables (ex: `${PATH}`, `${DISPLAY}`) and other PAM_ITEMs (ex: `@{PAM_SERVICE}`, `@{PAM_USER}`, etc.).  Take special note of `$` vs `@` here.

   PAM also handles the special variables `@{HOME}` and `@{SHELL}`, which expand to whatever is defined in `/etc/passwd`. *Note: in most PAM applications, the traditional variables `${HOME}` and `${SHELL}` (compare `@` vs `$`) are not available this early in PAM's flow.

   Using the example given in the comments of `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, this replacing/expanding behavior can be used to modify the `DISPLAY` variable for remote login sessions.

   ```
   /etc/security/pam_env.conf
   REMOTE_HOST     DEFAULT=localhost           OVERRIDE=@{PAM_RHOST}
   DISPLAY         DEFAULT=${REMOTE_HOST}:0.0  OVERRIDE=${DISPLAY}
   ```

To the specific problem you described here, the values you configured in `/etc/environment` weren't available in the `sudo` temporary environment because the `session` facility given by the PAM application definition for `/etc/pam.d/sudo` never calls `pam_env.so` for sessions.

In `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, sessions only import the rules from `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`.  Following the trail, in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, the session stack doesn't have an entry for `pam_env.so`.

---

There are a few ways to customize the variables available in a `sudo` environment.

If you need some custom set of environment variables that only exist in sudo-land, it's fairly straightforward.

1. Create a file to contain your exclusive-to-sudo environment variables.

   ```
   /etc/security/sudo_custom_vars.conf
   GREET   DEFAULT="hello from sudo land"
   VAR1    DEFAULT="${GREET}"
   _VAR2   DEFAULT="VAR2 not passed to sudo, ...but"
   VAR2    DEFAULT="${_VAR2} ${GREET}"                 OVERRIDE=${VAR2}
   VAR3    DEFAULT="Nope. Unknown users cannot sudo."  OVERRIDE=@{PAM_RUSER}
   ...
   ```
2. Make a copy of `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, rename it along the lines of `/etc/pam.d/sudo-environment`, and add a directive to the bottom of the `session` stack:

   ```
   session     required    pam_unix.so
   session     optional    pam_permit.so
   # Add a line for using pam_env.so
   session     optional    pam_env.so conffile=/etc/security/sudo_custom_vars.conf
   ```

   **If you want pass variables from the non-sudo environment, include the `user_readenv=1` flag**

   ```
   session     optional    pam_env.so      conffile=/etc/security/sudo_custom_vars.conf    user_readenv=1
   ```
3. In the PAM application definition `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, make the replacement:

   ```
   -   session    include       system-auth
   +   session    include       sudo-environment
   ```
4. Open a new terminal to test

   ```
   $ su <your username>                    # Testing PAM without logging out
   $ export VAR1=""
   $ export VAR2="hello from down here"    # Set var in non-sudo environment

   $ echo $VAR1
   <nothing>
   $ sudo sh -c 'echo $VAR1'               # Test sudo's DEFAULT value
   hello from sudo land

   $ echo $VAR2
   hello from down here
   $ sudo sh -c 'echo $VAR2'               # VAR2 not passed to sudo
   VAR2 not passed to sudo, ...but hello from sudo land
   $ sudo -E su -c 'echo $VAR2'            # VAR2 (and everything else) passed to sudo
   hello from down here
   $ sudo env VAR2="inline override" su -c 'echo $VAR2'
   inline override

   $ sudo sh -c 'echo $VAR3'               # Testing we can read a PAM_ITEM
   aaron
   ```

---

An alternative to tinkering around with the PAM modules is to edit `/etc/sudoers` with `# visudo`, as you did.  I realize this is an old question and way-back-when, commenting `Default env_reset` was the the thing to do.

Moving forward, the accepted best practice when using `sudoers` to pull in variable definitions from the environment is to append the variables to `env_keep`.  (...that is, unless you need a unique set of variables as shown above)

```
    /etc/sudoers
    Defaults env_keep += "var1 var2, etc..."
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get more or less what I wanted for sudo:

I edited the `/etc/sudoers` file (with `sudo visudo`) and commented out the lines `Default env_reset` and `Default secure_path = ...`.

Now sudo will use the user's environment.

The difference between `pam_env.conf` and `/etc/environment`still isn't clear to me tough, so the question is not yet answered.