# Why can't a process see environment variables set in /etc/environment?

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

I defined several environment variables in /etc/environment, but a process (build started by TeamCity) cannot see their values. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.. this is the content of my /etc/environment file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

CATALINA_BASE="/var/lib/tomcat7"
CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat7"

ACTIVEMQ_HOME="var/lib/activemq"
ACTIVEMQ_BASE="var/lib/activemq"
ACTIVEMQ_CONF="var/lib/activemq/conf"
ACTIVEMQ_DATA="var/lib/activemq/data"
ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms128m -Xmx192m"

M2_HOME="/usr/share/maven3"
MAVEN_HOME="/usr/share/maven3"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

The build started by TeamCity uses a Maven runner, and which at some point kicks an Ant build. Since the build was failing, I used Ant to print all environment variables in the system:

```
<!-- Provides all environment variables as Ant properties prefixed by "env.".
For example, CLASSPATH would be accessible in Ant as ${env.CLASSPATH} -->
<property environment="env"/>


<echo>List of all Environment Variables found in the system:</echo>
<echoproperties>
    <propertyset>
        <propertyref prefix="env."/>
    </propertyset>
</echoproperties>
```

Sure enough, the ones I set in /etc/environment don't show up.

The build agent running this is started using Ubuntu's Startup app's, where I configured it to run the command:

```
sudo -H -u administrator /bin/bash --login -c "~administrator/BuildAgent/bin/agent.sh start"
```

Could it be that this line runs before /etc/environment are set?

If I do a `echo $CATALINA_HOME` I see the value properly set, but the build for some reason cannot see it...

**NOTE**: Although I know it is the wrong way of doing it, I also tried adding `export` to the declarations inside `/etc/environment`, without any success. Then I removed it.

**NOTE 2**: I rebooted the machine after making changes to /etc/environment file, of course.

I'm on 14.04 LTS Server with minimal desktop installed (ubuntu-desktop --no--install-recommends) plus a few extras.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Read carefully [sudoers](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) man page Command environment section.

try -i option: if *sudo's -i option (initial login) is specified, sudoers will initialize the environment regardless of the value of env_reset.  The DISPLAY, PATH and TERM variables remain unchanged; HOME, MAIL, SHELL, USER, and LOGNAME are set based on the target user.  On AIX (and Linux systems without PAM), the contents of /etc/environment are also included.  All other environment variables are removed.*.

```
    sudo -u administrator -i "~administrator/BuildAgent/bin/agent.sh start"
```

If you are using PAM authentication, here is a useful link: [Difference between /etc/security/pam_env.conf and /etc/environment + making sudo read pam_env.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236083/difference-between-etc-security-pam-env-conf-and-etc-environment-making-sudo)

Comment: You linked to the manpage for Ubuntu 9.10; that does not have the content you quoted above (or would not, if it still existed), nor does the proper [14.04 sudo manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sudo.8.html#contenttoc5). I'm not sure which page you used, but modern versions of [the manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.man.html#Command_environment) specify that sudo reads `/etc/environment` only on "Linux systems without PAM."

Comment: I've confirmed that on a 14.04 system even with the `-i` or `--login` system, and a [properly configured `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144062/reading-from-etc-environment-with-sudo), `/etc/environment` is still not read. It looks like it may be a bug.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson thank you for your comments, I updated my answer up to 14.04 man page. I don't know if it is a bug, because now man page is different.